# Tooltip for each row in data table

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, tooltip, primefaces-extensions

This questions screams to be a duplicate of [JSF 2.0 + Primefaces 2.x: Tooltip for datatable row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980155/jsf-2-0-primefaces-2-x-tooltip-for-datatable-row) but since this old question has NO working/satisfying solution for me and there's no way (?) to get attention back to it I opened this new one.

It's very simple:
I have a  `dataTable` (with JSF-standard or with primefaces) and I'd like to add a different tooltip for EACH row (not just for one field in it!).

What I tried so far:

```
<pe:tooltip value="This is row number #{rowIndex}"
    for="@(#table1 tr[role=row][data-ri=#{rowIndex}])" 
    atPosition="top center" myPosition="bottom center"
    shared="true" />
```

where `#table1`is the ID of my data table . This came to my mind because of [this](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/tooltip/sharedTooltips.jsf).

And both solutions from [JSF 2.0 + Primefaces 2.x: Tooltip for datatable row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980155/jsf-2-0-primefaces-2-x-tooltip-for-datatable-row) : the first solutions works, but only for ONE field / id  and not for the whole row. The second solution won't work at all for me.

And I'm 100% sure that both - primefaces & primefaces extensions - are working for me, I tested it.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116670/tooltip-in-the-column-header-of-a-primefaces-datatable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've done some test and this approach works perfectly:

```
<p:dataTable var="entry" value="#{....}" styleClass="myTable" rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <p:column headerText="Header 1">
        <h:outputText value="#{entry.value1}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Header 2">
        <h:outputText value="#{entry.value2}" />
        <pe:tooltip value="This is row number #{rowIndex}" forSelector=".myTable tr[role=row][data-ri=#{rowIndex}]"
            shared="true" atPosition="top center" myPosition="bottom center" showDelay="500" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Note that in order to the **data-ri** attribute to be placed on datatable rows, you need the to add the attribute **rowIndex** (rowIndex="rowIndex").

It also worked with

```
<p:tooltip for="@(.myTable tr[role=row][data-ri=#{rowIndex}])" value="This is row number #{rowIndex}" />
```

Comment: That works nicely: The selector works for the full row, so it doesn't have to be defined for each column. The standard use-case would be to have e.g. value="entry.tooltiptext".
This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm getting `Cannot convert rowIndex of type class java.lang.String to int`. Any ideas?

Comment: change it to rowIndexVar

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it without using primefaces extensions. This example code works for me with primefaces 5.2.
Be aware that in primefaces 5.2 the p:dataTable attibute is **rowIndexVar** and not rowIndex as in the example above.

```
<h:form id="idform">

<p:dataTable var="komp" 
    id="idDataTable" 
    value="#{kompselect.listKomponenten}"
    rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
    selection="#{kompselect.selectedKomponente}"
    rowKey="#{komp.name}">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText id="otSelKomponente" value="#{komp.name}" />
        <p:tooltip  rendered="#{komp.displayToolTip}"
                for="idForm:iddataTable:#{rowIndex}:otSelKomponente"
                value="this is my Tooltip"/>

    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

according to this commment https://stackoverflow.com/a/13327334/4851983 (thaks BalusC ) 
Let primefaces link the objects automatically. I could show a tooltip for a textArea Primefaces 3.5  , as is show below

```
<p:dataTable id="commentsTable"
         value="#{historyReq.commentsFromReq}" var="comment"
         emptyMessage="#{localeMsg.roles_table_empty}" 
         rows="10"                                                                                                                                                               
         styleClass="myTable"
         rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

<p:column headerText="HEADER A">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.valorA}" />
</p:column> 

<p:column headerText="#{HEADER B}">                                                
        <p:inputTextarea  id="txtArea"  cols="45" rows="1"   
                           value="#{bean.valorB}" 
                           readonly="true" 
                           disabled="false"  
                           autoResize="false">
            <f:converter converterId="commentsConverter" />
        </p:inputTextarea>                                                                                                
         <p:tooltip for="txtArea" value="This is row number #{rowIndex}" />             
</p:column>
```

Comment: If I am not making a mistake, his example is a static one while you are trying to put an id on a component that will repeat over and over again. So on every row you have a text area with the same id, which will  not work.